# Regex to replace a string with special characters in shell

Tags: regex, shell

I have text file called sample.txt which contains

```
name="sam:18"
```

I want this to be replaced with the name given in configuration file which is called name.config which has

```
name="robin:19"
```

Here is my script which is called nameReplace.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source name.config
sed -i -e 's/name=[A-Za-z0-9]*/name=${name}/g' sample.txt
```

This executes but doesn't give any change in sample.txt.

I want the following output in sample.txt:

```
name="robin:19"
```

Please any help?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex:

```
name=[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

won't match:

```
name="sam:18"
```

Change your sed to:

```
sed -i.bak "s/name=.*/name=\"${name}\"/" sample.txt
```

Using double quotes here to be able to expand `$name` variable.